# ¿Como recorrer un array y validar si existen datos en otro array?

Tags: javascript, array, json, reactjs

Estoy tratando de comparar lo que tengo en un array con otro array, en contexto estoy obteniendo un array de un catalogo y otro de un Excel el cual lo estoy convirtiendo en array.
Necesito saber si lo que esta en el array que se obtuvo del Excel hay información en el otro, pero si no hay que me devuelva en este caso estoy buscando la existencia y quiero que me devuelva 0 en caso de que no exista en el catalogo original. El JSON original luce algo así

```js
const = catalogo [
  {
      codigo: 750123456789,
      nombre: "producto 1",
      existencia: 10,  
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456710,
      nombre: "producto 2",
      existencia: 30,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456711,
      nombre: "producto 3",
      existencia: 15,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456712,
      nombre: "producto 4",
      existencia: 30,
  },
]
```

y el otro arreglo que se obtiene luce algo así

```
const = pedido[
  {
      codigo: 750123456777,
      nombre: "producto 10",
      pedido: 10,  
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456710,
      nombre: "producto 2",
      pedido: 30,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456111,
      nombre: "producto 50",
      pedido: 15,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456712,
      nombre: "producto 4",
      pedido: 30,
  },
]
```

En este únicamente coinciden 2 y 2 no existen en el catalogo, quiero generar un arreglo en el cual me diga si hay existencia y si no me ponga un 0 algo así:

```
const = pedidoRevisado[
  {
      codigo: 750123456777,
      nombre: "producto 10",
      pedido: 10,
      existencia: 0,  
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456710,
      nombre: "producto 2",
      pedido: 30,
      existencia: 30,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456111,
      nombre: "producto 50",
      pedido: 15,
      existencia: 0,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456712,
      nombre: "producto 4",
      pedido: 30,
      existencia: 30,
  },
]
```

He estado tratando de hacerlo y lo hice atreves de un `forEch` y dentro el otro `forEach`, cuando busca las coincidencias si lo puedo realizar el problema es con los que no existen, realizo una condición y cuando no se cumplen por ende va recorriendo el arreglo del catalogo y aparecen el total de todos los artículos como si no estuvieran. les dejo un ejemplo de lo que tengo

```
    pedido.forEach(ped => {
        catalogo.forEach( cat => {
            if(ped.CODIGO === parseInt(cat.codigo)){
                arrayRevisar.push({
                    'codigo': ped.codigo,
                    'nombre': ped.nombre,
                    'pedido': ped.pedido,
                    'cedifa': cat.existencia
                });
            }else{
               //aqui nuevamente le puse el arrayRevisar pero al hacer todo el recorrido del arra de      catalogo me sale el total de elemento que tiene el array.
            }

        })

    });
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, y den antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que el siguiente código devuelve lo que tu indicas.

```
const catalogo = [
  { codigo: 750123456789, nombre: "producto 1", existencia: 10 },
  { codigo: 750123456710, nombre: "producto 2", existencia: 30 },
  { codigo: 750123456711, nombre: "producto 3", existencia: 15 },
  { codigo: 750123456712, nombre: "producto 4", existencia: 30 },
];

const pedido = [
  { codigo: 750123456777, nombre: "producto 10", pedido: 10 },
  { codigo: 750123456710, nombre: "producto 2", pedido: 30 },
  { codigo: 750123456111, nombre: "producto 50", pedido: 15 },
  { codigo: 750123456712, nombre: "producto 4", pedido: 30 },
];

const arrayRevisar = [];

pedido.forEach((ped) => {
  const existeEnCatalogo = catalogo.find((item) => item.codigo === ped.codigo);
  const agregarEnArrayRevisar = {
    codigo: ped.codigo,
    nombre: ped.nombre,
    pedido: ped.pedido,
  };
  if (existeEnCatalogo) {
    agregarEnArrayRevisar.existencia = existeEnCatalogo.existencia;
  } else {
    agregarEnArrayRevisar.existencia = 0;
  }
  arrayRevisar.push(agregarEnArrayRevisar);
});
```

Lo que hace básicamente es por cada pedido busca si este existe por su código en el array de catalogo, para esto utilicé el metodo find(), si es así devuelve sus datos con existencia, sino devuelve sus datos con existencia 0. El find a su vez nos devuelve el objeto que cumplió con la condición, por lo que podemos usar el dato existeEnCatalogo.existencia para agregarlo al arrayRevisar.

Dado que en ambos casos de agregan casi los mismos datos, cree un objeto con los datos que se repiten, y luego dentro del if/else solo agrego la key existencia con el value que corresponde, al finalizar hago un único push.

Dando en este caso como resultado un array con 4 objetos, 2 con exitencia con valor y 2 con existencia en 0.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tambien lo probe y me sirvio bastantes, Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo de como lo realizaría.

- En este caso yo recorro el objeto que me interesa conservar, que es el de pedido.
- En cada iteración busco si existe ese producto dentro de mi array de catalogo, y tomo el campo existencia, en caso contrario le dejo en 0.
- Al final de  cada iteración agrego una copia de mi ítem, a el array `pedidoRevisado`.

Nota.- No inserto el ítem de el ciclo, ya que como es un objeto se copiara el objeto y no una copia, por lo que si agrego la propiedad se modificara también en el array pedido.

Y este es mi ejemplo.

```js
const catalogo =[
  {
      codigo: 750123456789,
      nombre: "producto 1",
      existencia: 10,  
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456710,
      nombre: "producto 2",
      existencia: 30,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456711,
      nombre: "producto 3",
      existencia: 15,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456712,
      nombre: "producto 4",
      existencia: 30,
  },
];
const  pedido = [
  {
      codigo: 750123456777,
      nombre: "producto 10",
      pedido: 10,  
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456710,
      nombre: "producto 2",
      pedido: 30,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456111,
      nombre: "producto 50",
      pedido: 15,
  },
  {
      codigo: 750123456712,
      nombre: "producto 4",
      pedido: 30,
  },
];

var pedidoRevisado = [];

for (let item of pedido) {
  const itemCatalogo = catalogo.find((e) => e.codigo === item.codigo);
  const existencia = 0;
  if(existencia){
    existencia = itemCatalogo.existencia;
  }
  
  pedidoRevisado.push({
    codigo: item.codigo,
    nombre: item.nombre,
    pedido: item.pedido,
    existencia: existencia
  })
}

console.log(pedidoRevisado);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si me sirvio, me ayudaste bastante